# Science fiction book/novel about aliens in humans' bodies

Tags: story-identification, novel

Once in middle school we read in class this short story (probably the summary of a sci-fi book/novel) about an alien (I don't remember if he was from Mars or another solar system planet) that woke up in his alien city; everyone else was dead, and in the middle of a square he found a Device/Machine, all around it was full of dead bodies.

He pressed a button on the machine and instantaneously his mind was transferred to a human body on Earth.

Answer (score 21):

["The Last Martian"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55211), not a novel but a short story by [Fredric Brown](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?10), first published in [*Galaxy Science Fiction*, October 1950](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58628), which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v01n01_-_1950_-_World_Editions/page/n145/mode/2up), as is the [*X Minus One*](https://archive.org/details/OTRR_X_Minus_One_Singles/XMinusOne56-08-07063TheLastMartian.mp3) radio adaptation.

ISFDB synopsis:

> A drunk tells a strange story: he is from Mars. He noticed that everyone was seemingly dead, and there was a big button on a platform on the largest city on Mars.

Excerpts:

> He took a draught of the beer and put the glass down again, but kept his hands tightly around the glass, possibly to keep them from shaking.
>
> He said, "I'm a Martian. *The last one.* All the others are dead. I saw
> their bodies only two hours ago."
>
> "You were on Mars only two hours ago? How did you get here?"
>
> "I don't know. That's the horrible thing. I don't know. All I know is that the others were dead, their bodies starting to rot. It was awful. There were a hundred million of us, and now I'm the last one."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> My Martian went on talking. "We tried to develop space travel, but we couldn't. We thought some of us might escape the kryl, if we came to Earth or to other worlds. We tried, but we failed. We couldn't even get to Deimos or Phobos, our moons."
>
> "You didn't develop space travel? Then how — "
>
> "I don't know. *I don't know*, and I tell you it's driving me wild. I don't know how I got here. I'm Yangan Dal, *a Martian. And I'm here, in this body.* It's driving me wild, I tell you."
>
> [. . . .]
>
> "I saw it from the air, as I flew over the city. And there was something in the middle of the field, on a platform. I went down and hovered the targan — it's a little like your helicopters, I forgot to mention — I hovered over the platform to see what was there. It was some kind of a column made of solid copper. Copper on Mars is like gold is on Earth. There was a push-button set with precious stones set in the column. And a Martian
> in a blue robe lay dead at the foot of the column, right under the button. As though he'd pushed it — and then died. And everybody else had died, too, with him. Everybody on Mars, except me.
>
> "And I lowered the targan onto the platform and got out and I pushed the button. I wanted to die, too; everybody else was dead and I wanted to die, too. But I didn't. I was riding on a streetcar on Earth, on my way home from work, and my name was — "